# VBA: Showing specific Powerpoint slide in OLE Bound Object Frame

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ole

I am currently developing an application in Microsoft Access 2007. Inside a form, I'd like to load a powerpoint presentation into an OLE Bound Object Frame.
Basically, this can be done in VBA by the following macro:

```
Private Sub cmdPreview_Click()

    MsgBox Location 'Location refers to column name of current selected data row
    olePreview.OLETypeAllowed = acOLELinked
    olePreview.SourceDoc = Location
    olePreview.Action = acOLECreateLink

End Sub
```

This is working fine. However, only the first slide of a powerpoint presentation is depicted. How is it possible to load the second or third slide of this presentation file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this from Shyam Pillai.  It's VB6 code but might be adaptable to what you're trying to do:

http://skp.mvps.org/vb/pptvbwnd.htm